# show or hide columns in kendo ui grid + angular js

Tags: angularjs

I am using Kendo UI grid in angular js. Grid is displaying correctly.
but I want to hide a particular column based on user type.
I have tried like below, but its not working.
Here my angular controller code:

```
$scope.blogGridOptions = {
        dataSource: {
            pageSize: 10,
            autoBind: false,
            transport: {
        read: function (e) {
            $http.get('/Blog/GetAllBlogs')
              .then(function success(response) {
                  if (response.data.success) {
                      e.success(response.data.blogs);
                  }
              });
             gridCallback = e;
        }
            }
        },
        sortable: true,
        pageable: true,
        resizable: true,
        filterable: true,
        columns: [{
            field: "BlogTitle",
            title: "Blog Title",
            width: "300px",
            filterable: false
        }, {
            field: "BlogContent",
            title: "Blog Content",
            width: "300px",
            filterable: false
        }, {
            field: "ApprovalStatus.ApprovalStatus",
            title: "Approval Status",
            width: "300px",
            filterable: false
        }, {
            field: "Actions",
            width: "300px",
            template: function (e) {
                var str = '';

                str = str + '<a href="" ng-click="blog.editBlog(' + e.BlogId + ')">Edit</a>';

                str = str + '&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href="" ng-click="blog.deleteBlog(' + e.BlogId + ')">Delete</a>';

                return str;
            },
            filterable: false
        }, {
            hidden: function (e) { return e.userDetails.UserTypeId == 1 ? false : true; } ,
            title: "Approve",
            template: function (e) {
                return '<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="blog.approveBlogs(dataItem,2)"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></button>&nbsp;&nbsp;<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="blog.ignoreBlogs(dataItem,3)"><i class="fa fa-close "></i></button>';
            }
        }]
    }
```

MVC View code:

```
<div kendo-grid="blogGrid" options="blogGridOptions" id="gridBlog"></div>
```

if usertypeid is 1, that column should show, for other users, it should be hidden.

PLease help to resolve this issue.

Comment: Where does UserTypId come from? Is it set when the page is loaded(and the grid is rendered) or can it change on each fetch of the grid data(i.e. is part of the row data)?  Also, will it be potentially different for every row of the grid or will every row have the same value, i.e. do you want to hide the entire column or hide/show the Approve button on a row-by-row basis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use hidecolumn in your dataBound event that is on the options of the grid. Not sure where you are getting the userTypeId from, but let's say it's bound to the controller and the column's name is 'approved'

```
            dataBound: function(e) {
                if(vm.userDetails.UserTypeId !== 1){
                   this.hideColumn('approved');     
                }          
            },
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.